# Android: play custom notification sound, even if phone is muted and/or in DND mode

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I've created a personal (not public!) application long ago which receives notifications. Now I'm rewriting this application and I'm using notification channels. I already implemented a custom vibration pattern and all the things I need, but one thing is still missing:

The app should bypass DND mode. As far as I came, this works now. But if the phone is silent (`STREAM_*` levels 0), the sound is not played - *but it should*. Is there any possibility, to set the Volume for this notification to MAX? And yes, it's not a problem if the notification is received in foreground, but it also should play the sound in the background.

What I've got so far:

My `NotificationUtils.java` class which creates the Notification channel(s). This is the one that should bypass DND:

```
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean prefVibration = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATION_VIBRATE, false);
Boolean prefSound = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(Constants.PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATION_WITH_SOUND, false);
String prefSoundfile = mSharedPreferences.getString(Constants.PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATION_SOUNDFILE, "not");


String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
NotificationChannel alarmsChannel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, getString(R.string.channel_title_alarms), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        alarmsChannel.enableLights(true);
        alarmsChannel.enableVibration(true);
        alarmsChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        alarmsChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        alarmsChannel.setBypassDnd(true);
        alarmsChannel.setImportance(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        alarmsChannel.shouldShowLights();
        alarmsChannel.canBypassDnd();
if (prefVibration) {
        alarmsChannel.setVibrationPattern(mVibratePattern);
        alarmsChannel.shouldVibrate();
}

if (prefSound) {
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE + "://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + getResId(prefSoundfile, R.raw.class));
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
        alarmsChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
}

getManager().createNotificationChannel(alarmsChannel);
```

When a user enables the `Constants.PREFERENCES_NOTIFICATION_WITH_SOUND` preference, he is asked for the correct permissions:

```
ActivateDndAllowance mDndAllowance = new ActivateDndAllowance(this.getContext());
mDndAllowance.check();
```

In the notification receiver class, where I use the `NotificationCompat.Builder`,  I can just use a `MediaPlayer` instance and `AudioManager` to set the volumes. But this only works in foreground... or did I miss something?

How is it possible to adjust the volume (just for this notification), even in background?

Thanks a lot!